# Arc normal given by 3 points

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am struggling a bit to find the normal to an arc given by 3 points (in sequence). From my search, this is what I understand about calculating normal in 2D:

We can define 3 points A,B,C (in 2D) where B is between A and C and we want to find the normal at B which is given by:

N = [Ay - Cy;Cx - Ax];

Is this correct? If so, how do I calculate (literally) a point (lets say P) that lies on the normal at a distance (lets say d=7). To illustrate:

```
        P(x,y)
        |
        | d=7            
        B



A                     C
```

Please a advise - Thanks.

p.s. I would also appreciate some links to literature that explains ways to estimate normals in 2D (although I understand the problem of "normal" in 2D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **B is in the exact middle of arc**, then your normal is correct. There is ambiguity with +/- direction, but you can choose external normal direction using the sign of cross product of AB and BC vectors.

To find point P, you have to normalize N

```
N = (Nx, Ny)
Len(N) = Sqrt(Nx*Nx + Ny*Ny)  //Hypot is some math libraries
n = (Nx/Len, Ny/Len)
P = B + Dist * n
(Px, Py) = (Bx + Dist*nx, By + Dist*ny)
```

Comment: I am having trouble with checking the direction of the normal. Lets say my points are A(-4,-2), B(3,0) & C(1,1). Cross product of AB is -12 and BC is 3. N = (-3,5) from above. The point at a distance d should either be (+,+) or (+,-). How am I getting the latter?

Comment: This example doesn't satisfy B-middle property, so N is wrong

Comment: if Cross(AB,BC) >0 then negate both components of your N